# After making a copy of a matrix (list of lists), why does double indexing the copy change the original but indexing does not?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a matrix defined as a global variable:

```
BOARD = [
    [0, 0, 3],
    [2, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0]
]
```

However, when manipulating this matrix, I want to leave the original untouched and instead work on a copy. So I did this in the main function in order to make an independent copy:

`board = BOARD[:]`

As expected, the results of `board == BOARD` and `board is BOARD` are `True` and `False`, respectively. So when I make an edit like so `board[0] = [1, 0, 3]`, then only `board` is changed, which is fine. However, if I do `board[0][0] = 1`, then `BOARD` also changes, which is not what I expected. And stranger still, `board is BOARD` is still `False`.

Why is there this inconsistent behaviour and any suggestions on how I can get around it?

EDIT:

If I run:

```
board = BOARD[:]
board[0] = [1, 0, 3]
board[0][0] = 2
```

then `BOARD` does not change.

But I only added the single indexing for comparison. In the real program I want to be able to do this:

```
board = BOARD[:]
board[0][0] = 2
```

But this is where `BOARD` does change, even though I would like it to stay constant.

Comment: When i tried the last situation board[0][0] = 2 , i was able to create the same behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not getting this error. Here is my code:

```
BOARD = [
[0, 0, 3],
[2, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0]
]

board = BOARD[:]
print(board == BOARD) # prints True
board[0] = [1,0,3]
print(board == BOARD) # prints False
board[0][0] = 1 
print(board == BOARD) # still prints False
```

After reading AkThao's clarification I understood what was going on.

Python uses pointers to implement lists.
For example, if you set `a = [1,2,3]` and `b = a`. If you then modify `b[0] = 5`, `a` will also be modified because both a and b are pointers to the same memory location.

2D lists are implemented using a pointer to pointers (double pointer), i.e. a list of pointers like [p1, p2, p3].

When you do `board = BOARD[:]`, it creates a copy of the list, but it does not change the actual value of the pointers (the elements of the list). So, the list board will is essentially just a copy of the 3 different pointer values.

This is why when you do board[0][0] = 1, it changes the value of BOARD as well (because the actual pointer stored by board is unchanged).

When you do `board[0] = [1, 0, 3]` as I have done, you are changing the actual value of the pointer, which is why the original BOARD does not change afterwards.

Comment: It's true, the error does not appear when you have already changed `board` by doing `board[0] = [1, 0, 3]`. But I want to be able to only do `board[0][0] = 1` without first doing the previous step. And this is where the error occurs.

Comment: You're right. Thanks for clarifying. I've edited my answer to explain this behavior.

Comment: I've tried my best to explain the situation as clearly as possible. Please ask if you need any clarification. Hope I helped, and thanks for asking such an interesting question!

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, that's made everything clear now!

Answer (score 0):

Why does `BOARD` change at all?

BOARD and b are both references.

When coding vec = b you assign b address to BOARD. Therefore changing data in b will also "change" BOARD.

I have also tried every method to copy a list ,but one method was succesful,

```
b=copy.deepcopy(BOARD)
```

although the `deepcopy` is time consuming for large lists you can try it.

```
import copy
B = [
    [0, 0, 3],
    [2, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0]
]
print(B)

b=copy.deepcopy(B)

b[0][0] = 2

print(b)

print(B)
```

output:

```
[[0, 0, 3], [2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
[[2, 0, 3], [2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 0, 3], [2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

hope this helps you!

Comment: I understand that assigning one variable to another makes it another reference to the same object. However, this does not explain why one method of indexing seems to create a new, independent object and the other does not. But thank you for the `deepcopy` suggestion. I prefer to use `board = [row[:] for row in BOARD]`.